# how to increment an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to increment an int array using a variable as the increment but it throws an error.

```
int array[MAXSIZE];
int n;

//fill the array with some numbers
//some other code
```

The situation here is that once I analyze the first "n" numbers i will not need them again and it will be a waste of cycles to iterate the array from the starting so i want to increment the array by "n". 
NOTE: because of the type of the problem that I'm working on I cannot just 
save the position in a variable and start from that position later using array[position]; I have to increment the pointer permanently.

```
array += n;
```

and Throws this **error: incompatible type in assignment.**
I don't know in advance what "n" is going to be. I tried to use 
**array += sizeof(int)*n;** but it fails as well.

Comment: Array is not a pointer.

Comment: array is not a pointer.  it's type is int[MAXSIZE]

Comment: Just make a pointer and use that `int* p_toArray = array;`

Comment: An array is not a pointer. You cannot increment an array. (you could increment a pointer)

Comment: @George *Just make a pointer and use that `int* p_toArray = array;`*  Just be really careful about what `array` actually is, lest you be surprised by the result of something like `p_toArray++;`.  For a novice programmer, such code can be really bug-prone.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: What would someone expect `p_toArray++;` to do that it doesn’t?

Comment: Wouldnt p_toArray++; will only increment that pointer and not the original array?

Comment: @Ric You *can't* increment the "original array". The same as you can't increment the address of variable `int a;`.

Comment: Once an Array is declared, memory is allocated. It's not possible to extend the array as memory is contiguously allocated and if extended, memory has to be extended and memory may intersect with memory allocated to other variables leading to catastrophic results. Hence array size can't be changed once declared. Please try to use Linked list concept to achieve your idea.

Comment: For pointer arithmetic, 'array' converts to the type 'int * const'.  So, what you're doing is similar to declaring 'const int Two = 2;' and then expecting the compiler to accept 'Two += n'.

Comment: @Ryan *What would someone expect `p_toArray++;` to do that it doesn’t?*  Point to the next element of the array, perhaps, instead of the address immediately past the end of the array?  Or, depending on context, the reverse.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Eh? Moving the pointer to the next element of the array is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 2):

`int array[MAXSIZE];`
`array` is an array and not a pointer. You can not increment an array variable.
You can do something like:

```
int *p = array;
p += whatever;
```

just make sure that you don't deference `p` when it is pointing to any element beyond the last element of the array.

The fact that printing out `array` and `p` will give you the same output (address) does not make them the same things.

Comment: I thought  an array an a pointer was the same haha. However many times in my code im using the syntax array[x]. If I do what you are saying can I do p[x]; ?

Comment: @Ric Yes, you can :)

Comment: Sure you can and again make sure `x` is within a proper limit.

Answer (score 0):

an array name is a `type * const array_name` so you can't move it.(pay attention it is a const pointer)
you can define a pointer yourself and then move it. for example:

```
int *arr = new int[siz];
```

or in c:

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

if your source code is in a .c file, you do not need to do casting.

Comment: Have you noticed the language?

Comment: Even in `C++` , `int *arr = new int[siz];` is _usually_ pretty poor form.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and **is not an lvalue**. If the array
>   object has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

So you may not change an array such a way as

```
array += n;
```

So just use one more variable of the type `int *`. For example

```
int array[MAXSIZE];
int n;

//...

int *p = array;

p += n;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{

    int array*,i,n;

    printf("Enter size of array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    array = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    /* code to enter numbers in array */

    array += n;

    //remember to free pointers after you are done with them

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: ...and poorly indented. And `#DEFINE` should be in lower case.

Comment: Could you please explain how is it leaking memory? I'm willing to improve.

Comment: `malloc` a memory, then loose the original pointer making it impossible to free it afterward (not that this code is trying to..)

Comment: You mean to `free()` the pointer after it has been used? I assumed OP would know how to do that.

Comment: `malloc`ing memory just adds an unnecessary layer of complexity, that some people might see and think is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fill the array with data, then you will need to index into the array.

```
int array[MAXSIZE];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
    array[i] = rand();
}
```

If you genuinely want to make use of a pointer, and do 'pointer arithmetic' then you must be careful.

```
int array[MAXSIZE];
int *p;
int i;

p = &(array[0]);
for (i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
    *p = rand();
    p += 1;
}
```

Pointer arithmetic may not work as you expect... Doing `p += 1` does not move the pointer along one byte, or even one `int`, but it will move the address along the *size* of the variable's *de-referenced type*.

Do an experiment:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
    struct info {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    struct info array[10];
    struct info *p;
    int n;

    p = &(array[0]);

    printf("sizeof(*p): %zu\n", sizeof(*p));

    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        printf("address: %p\n", p);
        p += 1;
    }
}
```

This will advance `p`'s value by `sizeof(*p)` each time around the loop.